# Using javascript to get nested json into a comma separated list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, csv

This is what I have...

```
[{
  "programName": "Testing 102",
  "recommendedComparisons": [{
    "programName": "Testing 101",
    "id": 2
  }, {
    "programName": "Testing 401",
    "id": 4
  }],
  "id": 1,
  "programId": 3
}, {
  "programName": "Testing 101",
  "recommendedComparisons": [{
    "programName": "Testing 102",
    "id": 3
  }],
  "id": 9,
  "programId": 2
}]
```

What I want is two lists of recommendedComparisons.

`Testing 101, Testing 401` and `Testing 102`

I'm sure there must be simple way.

Comment: Please show expected results along with code that you have tried

Comment: I don't understand. What is wrong with just a JSON.parse() ?

Comment: @RayfenWindspear Nothing, Jean just hasn't researched the topic at all and is just going straight to answers.  This is one of the first things you learn how to handle when learning JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Making use of the `map` function allows to transform the object.

   `var recommendedComparisons = data.map(x => 
                               x.recommendedComparisons.map(x=>x.programName));`
2. Using [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get 2 list of results.

   `var [firstList,secondList] = recommendedComparisons;`

```js
var data = [{
  "programName": "Testing 102",
  "recommendedComparisons": [{
    "programName": "Testing 101",
    "id": 2
  }, {
    "programName": "Testing 401",
    "id": 4
  }],
  "id": 1,
  "programId": 3
}, {
  "programName": "Testing 101",
  "recommendedComparisons": [{
    "programName": "Testing 102",
    "id": 3
  }],
  "id": 9,
  "programId": 2
}];

var recommendedComparisons = data.map(x => x.recommendedComparisons.map(x=>x.programName));

var [firstList,secondList] = recommendedComparisons;
console.log(firstList);
console.log(secondList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{
  "programName": "Testing 102",
  "recommendedComparisons": [{
    "programName": "Testing 101",
    "id": 2
  }, {
    "programName": "Testing 401",
    "id": 4
  }],
  "id": 1,
  "programId": 3
}, {
  "programName": "Testing 101",
  "recommendedComparisons": [{
    "programName": "Testing 102",
    "id": 3
  }],
  "id": 9,
  "programId": 2
}];

var result = data.map(function(item) {
    return item.recommendedComparisons.map(function(comp) {
        return comp.programName;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the *Array* object's **map** function.

You are looking for just the *program names* of the *recommended comparisons*. For that, you would need 1 map function to get the comparisons, then you would need to call map again, and inside that function call map on the subarrays to return the program names.

Since you mentioned *comma-separated-lists*, it would be better to not return the array itself. Instead create a new string, and join the subarrays with a comma, appending it with a new line.

I believe this is what you are looking for

```js
var array = [{"programName":"Testing 102","recommendedComparisons":[{"programName":"Testing 101","id":2},{"programName":"Testing 401","id":4}],"id":1,"programId":3},{"programName":"Testing 101","recommendedComparisons":[{"programName":"Testing 102","id":3}],"id":9,"programId":2}]

var results = array.map(function(a) { return a.recommendedComparisons
  }).map(function(b) {
      return b.map(function(c) {
          return c.programName;
      });
  });

var str = "";

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    str += results[i].join(',') + "\n"
}

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test this out yet but I'm pretty sure this is right. I'll test it now.

```
const list = [
  {
    "programName":"Testing 102",
    "recommendedComparisons":[
      { "programName": "Testing 101", "id":2 },
      { "programName": "Testing 401", "id":4 }
    ],
    "id":1,
    "programId":3
  },
  {
    "programName":"Testing 101",
    "recommendedComparisons":[
       {"programName":"Testing 102","id":3}
    ],
    "id":9,
    "programId":2
  }
];

let listOfComparisonLists = [];

list.map((program) => {
  const programNames = program.recommendedComparisons.map((comp) => comp.programName);

  listOfComparisonLists.push(programNames);
});

console.log(listOfComparisonLists); // [['Testing 104', 'Testing 401'],['Testing 102']]
```

Comment: Three hours later... have we confirmed whether your code works as advertised?

Comment: Yeah, it works. I accidentally put `append` instead of `push`.